# PHP 7.1.0 connection issue to SQL2008 R2

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, iis-7.5, php-7.1

I am trying to migrate an app from SQL2000 to SQL2008 R2.

I've installed onto a Windows 2008 R2 (64 bit) server IIS7.5, PHP 7.1.0, downloaded the `php_pdo_sqlsrv_7_nts_x64.dll` and `php_sqlsrv_7_nts_x64.dll` files and added to the `php.ini` file (`ext`), followed the online advice I could find but alas - no joy !!

Not sure what I'm doing wrong - any help would be appreciated.

Thank you in anticipation.

Comment: What problems are you encountering?

Comment: Hi, phpinfo.php doesn't show any sqlserver references as I scroll down and a db conn. within a simple php page I've written will echo text but crashes immediately I use sqlsrv_connect or sqlsrv_connect.

Comment: sorry, last post should only have one sqlsrv_connect

Comment: First : Have you edited  the good php.ini file ? Is php.ini file mentionned in phpinfo the same file ?

Comment: Hi, I believe it is the correct file - and it contains the following additions [PHP_PDO_SQLSRV_7_NTS_X64]
extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_7_nts_x64.dll
[PHP_SQLSRV_7_NTS_X64]
extension=php_sqlsrv_7_nts_x64.dll

Answer (score 0):

Moved the app to windows 2012 R2, SQL 2008 R2 and installed the 32 bit php drivers. All is working now. Thank you for the help CGritton and Alexandre T.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue, using PHP 7.1 and PHP SQL SVR 4.0 driver, both are 64 bit, the driver was not loaded correctly. It might be that the driver is not compatible yet. Changing the PHP to 7.0.14 (and below), the driver is loaded perfectly.

**update:**
the official release is not supporting PHP7.1 yet, but there is a preview build that can be loaded by PHP7.1. see this bug report: https://github.com/Microsoft/msphpsql/issues/193

and this preview build (link from the bug report above): https://github.com/Microsoft/msphpsql/releases/tag/4.1.4-Windows

note that it will change in the future.